# Cannot install virtualbox on 18.04

Tags: virtualbox

I had Virtualbox installed fine on 18.04 but after an upgrade (`sudo apt upgrade`) this morning it doesn't seem to work:

```
Loading new virtualbox-5.2.10 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-15-generic
Building initial module for 4.15.0-15-generic
Done.
At main.c:281:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:74
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:81
kmodsign: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.10/4.15.0-15-generic/x86_64/module/virtualbox.ko: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Is this a temporary problem with the repos or something wrong my end?

EDIT: [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1766215)

Comment: virtualbox has been working with 18.04 for weeks now. It was until the upgrade from 5.2.10-dfsg-1 to 5.2.10-dfsg-2 came out that this problem started for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok the answer for now is actually to uninstall the ubuntu apt version of Virtualbox and go with the package over on Virtualbox's site. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads You will clearly see the one marked Bionic. Doing some digging and dfsg-2 is coming from  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse. You might try also seeing if the following the Debian based Linux distributions instructions produces a stabler build. I haven't done that yet.

Comment: I found it wouldn't show up in the installed applications, but it did after I started it from a shell.